# Deny access to all files except one from subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to restrict access to all files in my home directory, then to allow only one main php file from a subdirectory using one .htaccess file, but it does not work as expected. It shows only "Forbidden" for every request. How to make it work as expected?

Now I am using :

```
order allow,deny

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /path_to_file/index.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Do you want to deny access too all files except one  (like you say in your question), or do you want to redirect everything to your PHP facade (like it looks from your code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just forward all requests to that particular file. Put this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/subdir/file\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /subdir/file.php [QSA]
```